# why connection Read return the length of buffer, not really send?

Tags: sockets, go

I am writing a pair of socket server and client in Golang.

Here is my code for client:

```
func handler(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()
    buffer := make([]byte, 2048)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for {
        nbytes, err := reader.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Printf("client: send %d bytes -> %s", nbytes, buffer)

        _, err = conn.Write(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
```

code for server:

```
func serverHandler(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()
    buffer := make([]byte, 2048)
    for {
        nbytes, err := conn.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            log.Print("Error reading: ", err.Error())
        }
        log.Printf("server: %d bytes received -> %s", nbytes, buffer)

        writer := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
        _, err = writer.Write(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print("Error writing: ", err.Error())
        }
        writer.Flush()
    }
}
```

Here is some output:

```
./server 12345
2019/12/24 00:35:31 Listen on localhost:12345
2019/12/24 00:35:38 client from: 127.0.0.1:51352
2019/12/24 00:35:48 server: 2048 bytes received -> hello?


./client localhost 12345
hello?
2019/12/24 00:35:48 client: send 7 bytes -> hello?
```

As you can see, client sent 7 bytes, but the server received 2048 bytes. what is the problem of server's code?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't send 7 bytes, you sent 2048. You're passing the `buffer` to `conn.Write`, and it writes all 2048 bytes of it. To send only the number of bytes read, you should only send the part that has the data you read:

```
 _, err = conn.Write(buffer[:nbytes])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this help me a lot.